# How can I check if a file exists with a certain string in its filename?

Tags: php

I'd like to be able to search a directory for a file that starts with a specific string, for example:

```
- foo
  - 1_foo.jpg
  - 2_bar.png
```

How would I check directory foo for files that begin with "1_"?

I've tried using file_exists and preg_match like so:
`if (file_exists("foo/" . preg_match("/^1_/", "foo/*"))) echo "File exists.";`
but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need the `glob()` function. The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells.

```
<?php
foreach (glob('1_*.*') as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
1_foo.png
1_bar.png
1_something.png
```

Comment: Oh, cool, that's exactly what I needed. Weird function name though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the filesystem doesn't understand wildcards or regular expressions.  To accomplish what you want, you have to open the directory and read its contents, getting a list of all the files in that directory.  Then you use standard string utilities to see which filenames match your criteria.

I think [PHP's scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) is what you want as a starting point.  You can also use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) but that actually forks a shell to get the file list (which in turn will do the C equivalent of `scandir()`).

Comment: Ah, bummer. Wishful thinking for the future then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function

```
<?php
$list = glob('1_*.*');
var_dump($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having some trouble checking a directory and files and I gather some scripts here and there and this worked for me (Hope it helps u too):

```
if ($handle = opendir('path/to/folder/')) 
{
    while ( false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)) ) {
        if ( $entry != "." && $entry != ".." ) {
        // echo "$entry<br>";
            if (preg_match("/^filename[0-9]_[0-9].jpg/", $entry))
            {
                // $found_it = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```